# Firebase RecordCustomExceptionName usage for C# exceptions

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, crashlytics

I am having difficulties using the `RecordCustomExceptionName` method of *Firebase Crashlytics* and I cannot find any documentation on how to create an instance of Firebase.Crashlytics.StackFrame[]. The goal is logging unhandled C# exceptions in Crashlytics. So in essence what **I need to do is to somehow convert a C# `Exception` object into a `Firebase.Crashlytics.StackFrame[]` array object.**

Please can anyone help by providing details on how this can be achieved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all `RecordCustomExceptionName` method
 can be used to record a single exception structure in a report. This is particularly useful when your code interacts 
with non-native languages like Lua, C#, or Javascript. **This call can be expensive and should only be used shortly before process termination.** 
This API is not intended be to used to log NSException objects.

> All safely-reportable NSExceptions are automatically captured by
>   Crashlytics.

**Now point 2:** `I need to do is to somehow convert a C# Exception object into a Firebase.Crashlytics.StackFrame[] array object.`

Actually there is no direct way to report **System.Exception** to Crashlytics, what you can do then? Convert it to NSError and use **RecordError(NSError error)** method.

> You can manage it like this way:

```
public static void CreateCrashReport(Exception ex, string extra = null)
{
    var crashInfo = new Dictionary<object, object>
    {
        [NSError.LocalizedDescriptionKey] = ex.Message + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extra) ? extra : ""),
        ["StackTrace"] = ex.StackTrace,
    };

    var error = new NSError(new NSString(ex.Message),
        -1001,
        NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(crashInfo.Values.ToArray(), crashInfo.Keys.ToArray(),
        crashInfo.Keys.Count));

    Crashlytics.SharedInstance.RecordError(error);
}
```

**Reference:** https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Classes/Crashlytics.html#//api/name/recordCustomExceptionName:reason:frameArray:

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct `Nuget Package` for Xamarin Forms to use **Firebase Crashlytics** . You need to add each Nuget Package for each Platform (iOS and Android).

**Android** : Install ***[Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/Crashlytics)*** Nuget Package ,and there is a sample inside it .

- Make sure you have a project setup in the Firebase Developer Console.
- Download your project's `google-services.json` file and place it in the folder of your Xamarin.Android project.
- Add the `Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics` NuGet package.
- Restart your IDE
- Add `google-services.json` to your Xamarin.Android app project.
- Set the build action of `google-services.json` to GoogleServicesJson
- Create a string resource with the name `com.crashlytics.android.build_id`. The value can be whatever you want to uniquely identify a particular build with.
- Clean and Rebuild your solution.

Then you can initialize the Crashlytics SDK with the following code in your main activity's `OnCreate`:

```
Fabric.Fabric.With(this, new Crashlytics.Crashlytics());

Crashlytics.Crashlytics.HandleManagedExceptions();
```

**iOS** : Install ***[Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/samples/Firebase/Crashlytics/CrashlyticsSample/ViewController.cs)*** Nuget Package ,and there is a sample inside it.

In `AppDelegate.cs` :

```
using Firebase.Crashlytics;

Crashlytics.Configure ();

Fabric.Fabric.SharedSdk.Debug = true;
```

In `ViewController.cs` :

```
using Firebase.Crashlytics;

Crashlytics.SharedInstance.RecordCustomExceptionName(...)
```

Comment: I cannot see "Crashlytics.SharedInstance.RecordCustomExceptionName" in ViewController.cs

Comment: @SachK That's my code in `ViewController.cs` , have you installed Nuget Package in Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: Yes I have installed it, the Firebase setup is all fine. The original question relates to the usage of the RecordCustomExceptionName. If you know how to use this method then please let me know.

Comment: @SachK I haven't used before. The follow code you can have 
 a try :`Crashlytics.SharedInstance.RecordCustomExceptionName("HandledException", "Some Reason",new StackFrame[0]);` All safely-reportable NSExceptions are automatically captured by Crashlytics. And you can have a look at its doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/crashlytics/api/reference/Classes/Crashlytics#-recordcustomexceptionname:reason:framearray: